# ¿Porque cuando uso git clone me descarga archivos protegidos?

Tags: github, git-bash

Actualmente tengo un repositorio en GitHub y para descargarlo uso GitBash, la forma en que lo descargo es con el siguiente comando:

> git clone *remote repository url*

Pero al momento de que ya lo tengo descargado y lo importo en visual studio me sale que los archivos están protegidos, abro los archivos y me es posible modificarlos y guardarlos pero los cambios no se guardan, el repositorio lo subi de la siguiente forma:

```
git init
git add --ignore-errors .
git commit "mensaje"
git remote add origin https://github.com/NOMBRE_USUARIO/NOMBRE_PROYECTO.git
git push origin master  --force
```

Cuando descargo el proyecto mediante la plataforma web de github no me salen los archivos protegidos.

Comment: Buenas. ¿Que sistema operrativo estas usando y que permisos se les asigna a los archivos que estas clonando?.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que se deba a los permisos que esta recibiendo en el sistema operativo o ya los has subido protegidos. Una de dos. Prueba a cambiarle los permisos y ponle todos.